# There is something wrong with this class (about a 2D array) i made in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2d

**This code bellow declares and initialized and prints a 2D array in console :**

```
    package tp_poo_v1_build1;
public class UI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] carte = new int[5][5];


        for(int i=0;i<carte.length;i++){         
            for(int j=0;j<carte[i].length;j++){
                carte[i][j]='X';
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < carte.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" | ");
            for (int j = 0; j < carte[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.print((char)carte[i][j] +" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }  
}
```

**it outputs :**

```
run:
 | X | X | X | X | X | 
 | X | X | X | X | X | 
 | X | X | X | X | X | 
 | X | X | X | X | X | 
 | X | X | X | X | X | 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**So, the problem is that, i wanted to use this code using a class called :**

> Grille.jave

**and so i tried this code below for the Class "Grille"**

```
package tp_poo_v1_build1;
public class Grille {
    int nbrL,nbrC; 
    int [][] carte= new int[nbrL][nbrC];
    public Grille(int pNbrL,int pNbrC){      //constructor 
        nbrL=pNbrL;
        nbrC=pNbrC;
        /*for(int[] i:carte)// enhanced for loop ( for each )
            for(int j:i)
                i[j]='X';*/

        for(int i=0;i<carte.length;i++){ // syntax  not optmised !
            for(int j=0;j<carte[i].length;j++){
                carte[i][j]='X';//Char in int 'X' == 88
            }
        }
    }
    boolean estLibre(int x,int y) {
        return (carte[x][y] == 'X');
    }
    public void liberer(int x, int y){
        carte[x][y]='X';
    }
    public void occupe(int x,int y,char nom){
       //...!
    }
    public void afficher(){//nbrL=carte.length and nbrC=carte[i].length ?
      System.out.println("THE Grill: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < carte.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" | ");
            for (int j = 0; j < carte[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(carte[i][j] +" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**and for the class that has the main method called :**

> UI.java

**it's code is bellow :**

```
package tp_poo_v1_build1;
public class UI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grille g=new Grille(5,5);
        g.afficher();
    }  
}
```

**it outputs :**

```
run:
THE Grill: 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

which is not what i want so if somebody knows what wrong please help.

**why is it that when i try to fill the array and print it print using the main method directly, it works fine but when i fill and declare the array using the constructor "Grille" and the method "afficher" to print it, by creating the object "G" of the class "Grille" and then calling the method "afficher" in the main method, it does print the message "The Grill" but not the array like in the previous code ?** 
**i just can't find out why so please help !!**

and thank you in advance. (sorry if it's a stupid question im new to java and programming in general  )
i'm new to this site so if my post is wrong please forgive me and help me correct it .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your carte array in the constructor!

Before the constructor:

```
 int [][] carte;
```

In the constructor:

```
 public Grille(int pNbrL,int pNbrC){      //constructor 
    nbrL=pNbrL;
    nbrC=pNbrC;

    carte = new int[nbrL][nbrC];

    //rest of the constructor
}
```

Comment: No problem! It did not work becouse when you initialized it before both nbrL and nbrC where 0 (before the contructor) so you created an empty array basically.